# How to send data from controller to model and send model variables to controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I send data to my model to do the logical processing and send data in some variables back to the controller so that it returns json?

I tried to do the same below, but I did not succeed i have the following message:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `infected=' for 
>   Class:0x00007f8d780d5d10

I'm trying to retrieve the infected, non_infected, and points_lost of my models variables.

Controller:

```
def index
    @survivor = Survivor.all
    @survivor_infected = Survivor.where(infected: true)
    @survivor.estimative (@survivor_infected)

    render json: { infected: "#{@survivor.infected}%",
                   non_infected: "#{}%",
                   points_lost: ""
                 }
  end
```

My models:

```
def self.estimative (s_infected)
    @survivor_infected = s_infected
    @water = []
    @water_price = []
    @food = []
    @food_price = []
    @medication = []
    @medication_price = []
    @ammunition = []
    @ammunition_price = []

    @survivor_infected.each do |s|
      @water << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Water").pluck(:quantity).join.to_i
      @water_price << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Water").pluck(:price).join.to_i
      @food << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Food").pluck(:quantity).join.to_i
      @food_price << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Food").pluck(:price).join.to_i
      @medication << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Medication").pluck(:quantity).join.to_i
      @medication_price << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Medication").pluck(:price).join.to_i
      @ammunition << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Ammunition").pluck(:quantity).join.to_i
      @ammunition_price << s.inventory.items.where(item: "Ammunition").pluck(:price).join.to_i
    end

    self.infected = ((@survivor_infected.count * 100)/(self.count))
    non_infected =((@survivor_infected.rewhere(infected: false).count * 100)/(self.count))
    points_lost = ( @water.reduce(:+) * @water_price.reduce(:+)) + (@food.reduce(:+) * @food_price.reduce(:+)) + (@medication.reduce(:+) * @medication_price.reduce(:+)) + (@ammunition.reduce(:+) * @ammunition_price.reduce(:+))

  end
```

Someone can help?

Comment: is infected a row in your database schema?

Comment: what u want to see from model in the controller ? U can return and initiate new variable of the object.

Comment: You can change `def self.estimative` to `def estimative`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut method "def estimative(s_infected)" from MODEL and place it in Controller.
2. I think instance variables ("@water ..") are not supported in MODEL because of security issues